# how to write mongodb query in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to do spatial search in my android app. I am trying to write mongodb query in java but unable to do so. 
How to use this mongodb query in java

`db.places.find( { loc: { $geoWithin :
                          { $center : [ [longitude, latitude], 10 ] }
                } } )`

I am new to mongodb and spatial search.

Please help!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/ I guess you are using this driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the api: http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.11.1/

```
BasicDBList geoCoord = new BasicDBList();
    geoCoord.add(longitude);
    geoCoord.add(latitude);

    BasicDBList geoParams = new BasicDBList();
    geoParams.add(geoCoord);
    geoParams.add(10);

    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("loc", 
        new BasicDBObject("$geoWithin", 
            new BasicObject("$center", geoParams)
        )
    );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer :) it worked for me,, can you please tell me what it is the unit of radius in this query. Is it meter or miles? Can we explicitly define the unit of radius or is it pre-defined?